# php image gallery

Tags: php, mysql, image, loops, galleria

I have setup a new image gallery where the images are stored on the server in /images/ folder and the respective details are stored in a mysql database (title, description, imagesrc).

What I am trying to do however is to pull back all of the images that are stored in the folder on the server without having to list them in html. I have got the php pulling back the correct fields and populating the gallery correctly, but when a new image is added to the library or one of the original images is updated then it obviously wont pull through on my site.

My code is:

```
<div id="galleria"><!-- Begin Galleria -->
        <div>
                <a href="<?php mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['imagesrc'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>">
                <img src="<?php mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['imagesrc'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>" alt='' title='' />
        </a>
        <strong><?php mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['title'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?></strong>
        <span><?php mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['desc'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?></span>
        </div>
        <div>
                <a href="<?php mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['imagesrc'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>">
                <img src="<?php mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['imagesrc'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>" alt='' title='' />
        </a>
        <strong><?php mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['title'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?></strong>
        <span><?php mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['desc'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?></span>
        </div>
        <div>
```

What is the best way to retrieve this information in a loop - I am not very skilled in php (as you can see from my code!) so would appreciate any help and guidance on building such a loop into this script to populate the gallery based on all the images that are in the folder.

thanks!!

JD

Comment: http://www.phpjabbers.com/ask91-read-files-name-in-folder-using-php.html - there's a scipt there by Arian Acosta. Keep in mind though that you won't get descriptions or meaningful strings for alt attribute this way. I reckon db setup is better, you just need to make sure all images exist in the folder. But I reckon it's worth a hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple query like this, you could just iterate through the whole table and populate your gallery in one while loop, like this:

```
<?php

mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<a href="' . $row['imagesrc'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a>';
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Which prints:

```
<a href="imagesrc1">Imagetitle1</a>
<a href="imagesrc2">Imagetitle2</a>
<a href="imagesrc3">Imagetitle3</a>
...
```

And you can mix whatever divs, spans and other fields (like $row['desc']) you need inside the while loop, eg.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<a href="' . $row['imagesrc'] . '">';
    echo '<img src="' . $row['imagesrc'] . '" />';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<strong>' . $row['title'] . '</strong>';
    echo '<span>' . $row['desc'] . '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Which would print:

```
<div>
    <a href="imagesrc1"><img src="imagesrc1" /></a>
    <strong>imagetitle1</strong>
    <span>desc1</span>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="imagesrc2"><img src="imagesrc2" /></a>
    <strong>imagetitle2</strong>
    <span>desc2</span>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="imagesrc3"><img src="imagesrc3" /></a>
    <strong>imagetitle3</strong>
    <span>desc3</span>
</div>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to execute the query again and again just execute it once and when thr records fetched in while loop put your div as per your requirement by using if( if required). I am showing you a sample of code which i used recently.

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,"",DB);
$query1="select dev_image,dev_name from developers";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
$cnt=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    //$dev_name=row['dev_name'];
{               
   $dev_image=$row['dev_image'];
   $dev_name=$row['dev_name'];
    if($cnt%4==0) {
    echo "<div class=\"project_main\">";
}
if($cnt%4==0) { 
        echo "<div class=\"project_img_main\">";
        echo "<div class=\"project_img1\">";
        echo "<img src=\"$dev_image\" alt=\"\" title=\"Project-1\" border=\"none\" />";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"project_img_name\">";
        echo "<p align=\"center\" class=\"txt1\">".$dev_name."</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
} else {
        echo "<div class=\"project_img_main1\">";
        echo "<div class=\"project_img1\">";
        echo "<img src=\"$dev_image\" alt=\"\" title=\"Project-1\" border=\"none\" />";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"project_img_name\">";
        echo "<p align=\"center\" class=\"txt1\">".$dev_name."</p>";
    echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
}

$cnt++;
if($cnt%4==0) {
    echo "</div>";
}
}

?>
```

I hope it will be useful for you..just made it accordingly.

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the MySQL connection through mysql_close(), so this will not work. The steps you want to execute are:

```
mysql_connect
mysql_select_db
mysql_query (or multiple queries, if placement matters)
mysql_close
```

Comment: love this place - so many experts willing to help! I have one more issue - is it possible to resize the images within this loop. Essentially they all have different widths, but I would like to make the height constant at 450px regardless of the original size......
Again, any help much appreciated!
Thanks